# Reduce network lag in game, is p2p better than client/ server?

Tags: network-programming, game-engine, lag

I am writing a 3rd person tank shooter game and ask this about networking:

1/ I think P2P is fairer for player because the ping is about similar in each pair of players (the same distance) while client/ server will has lower ping for nearby player and higher ping for another, is it true?

2/ The game is for fun, so I can trust clients, and if I can trust client, is there any technique for better lag compensation than traditional model where you can not trust clients?

Answer (score 2):

I am developing a program that uses the network just a much as any game, and we use a mix of the two.

Our client programs act as a server in a background process, which is handled by our dedicated server.

so instead of p2p, the client with the strongest connection is the server for the other clients. Our dedicated server makes that decision, and gives connection info to all other clients.